# Single Sign On with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, single-sign-on, subdomain

We have several ColdFusion sites all hosted as separate IIS7.5 sites on the same machine and accessible via sub domains. So for example

www.domain.com

forums.domain.com

portal.domain.com

profile.domain.com

User accounts are created for clients who can then login to the sites. We would like to implement a Single sign on solution for all the sites.

Could someone point me in the right direction for doing this in ColdFusion?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

We have a CAS and use ColdFusion for logging in over several servers (similar to what you describe).  The interaction between ColdFusion and the CAS is via the a slightly modified version of the ColdFusion CAS client developed by UC Davis.

here you can find [some details](https://confluence.ucdavis.edu/confluence/display/IETP/CAS+Cold+Fusion+Clients) on that.

Comment: Thanks John, Yeah CAS looks like it could be a good solution though I can't really find any info on getting the server part of it up and running in a Windows Server 2008/IIS 7.5/ColdFusion 9 environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cflogin, make sure all of your applicationToken attributes on the cflogin tags are  the same.  You may need to name your applications the same too (Application.cfc > this.name). Login sessions will persist from site to site.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7db9.html

Comment: If the sites have the same application name you don't have to worry while they're on the same server. You don't have to use cflogin either, you can roll your own login script if you want, anything that will set session variables indicating they are logged in.

Comment: The down side of this is that each area will end up using the same application scope variables as well so for example if you set your data source name in your application scope, application.myDSN you would share that across all sites.  I've set up sites that have the domain name as the dsn so when the application loads the dsn is set to myDomainCom.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I can't get this method to work, the sites all share the application structure but the session scope is still separate, each having unique sessionids.

Comment: As Travis said, if they're on the same server, then just make sure the application names are the same.  You will probably need to restart the ColdFusion Application Service for these to sync up.